# IF ELSE statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax-error, conditional-statements

I want to ask the question "What format do you want to use?", then, depending on whether the answer is `xml` or `json`, print the appropriate output. However, if it is not `xml` or `json`, then the code finishes.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -e -p "What format do you want to use? json/xml?: " format

if [[ "${format,,}" == "json" ]]; then
    curl=$curl"\"\Content-Type: application/json\"\
else [[ "${format,,}" == "xml" ]]; then
    curl=$curl"\"\Content-Type: application/xml\"\
elif [[ "${format,,}" == "no" ]]; then
  echo "Goodbye, you must specify a format to use Rest"
else 
  echo "Unknown"
  exit 0
fi
echo $curl
```

I receive this error when I try to run it:

```
[root@osprey groups]# ./test3
What format do you want to use? json/xml?: xml
./test3: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./test3: line 8: `elif [[ "${format,,}" == "no" ]]; then'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a bit longer, but much more user-friendly variant:

```
err() { echo "$@" >&2; return 1; }

show_help() {
cat - >&2 <<EOF
You must specify a format to use Rest because bla bla...
EOF
}

select_format() {
    PS3="Select the format do you want to use?> "
    select ans in json xml "quit program"; do
        case "$REPLY" in
            [0-9]*) answer=$ans;;
            *) answer=$REPLY;;
        esac
        case "${answer,,}" in
            '') ;;
            j|js|json) echo '-H "Content-Type: application/json"' ; return 0 ;;
            x|xml)     echo '-H "Content-Type: application/xml"'  ; return 0 ;;
            q|quit*)   err "Bye..." ; return 1;;
            h|help)  show_help ;;
            *) err "Unknown format $answer" ;;
        esac
    done
    [[ "$answer" ]] || return 1 #handles EOF (ctrl-D)
}

curl_args=()
curl_args+=( $(select_format) ) || exit 1
echo curl "${curl_args[@]}"
```

It shows a menu:

```
1) json
2) xml
3) quit program
Select the format do you want to use?>
```

and the user could enter:

- either the corresponding number
- or `j`, `js`, `json` for json and `x`, `xml` for the xml
- `h` for the help
- and `q` for the quit...
- incorrect (mistyped) answers are handled and asking again...

Comment: That's a really good way to represent the code i'm trying to write and it will definitely come in handy. Thank you

Comment: @Aaron yvw - enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -e -p "What format do you want to use? json/xml?: " format

if [[ "${format,,}" == "json" ]]; then
    curl=$curl"\"Content-Type: application/json\""
elif [[ "${format,,}" == "xml" ]]; then
    curl=$curl"\"Content-Type: application/xml\""
elif [[ "${format,,}" == "no" ]]; then
  echo "Goodbye, you must specify a format to use Rest"
else 
  echo "Unknown"
  exit 0
fi
echo $curl
```

Should work. If it does not, the problem is not with the if/else statements.

Edit: Found the problem. It was incorrect use of quotation marks. I tried to fix it, so the above should work now.

Comment: I've included the error message in my question if that would help even more

Comment: No worries. For future troubles, see [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) before you post here.

Answer (score 1):

Options and arguments should be stored in an array, not a single string. Further, a `case` statement would simpler here.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl_opts=()
read -r -e -p "What format do you want to use? json/xml?: " format

shopt -s nocasematch
case $format in
  json) curl_opts+=(-H "Content-Type: application/json") ;;
  xml)  curl_opts+=(-H "Content-Type: application/xml") ;;
  no)  printf 'Goodbye, you must specify a format to use Rest\n' >&2
       exit 1
       ;;
   *) printf 'Unknown format %s, exiting\n' "$format" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
esac

curl "${curl_opts[@]}" ...
```

Comment: That's interesting, I will research that because I'm building a script with multiple IF statements meaning this will be easier.
Although this code threw an error - see edit

Comment: I forgot a handful of `;;` to terminate each separate case; read about the `case` statement in the `bash` man page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
if ...
elif ...
else ...
fi
```

`else` must be followed by commands, not a condition and `; then`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I've followed that format but still no luck with the code. I've edited my question to give you an update. Any thoughts?